# How to get correct output from regex.split()?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
number_with_both_parantheses = "(\(*([\d+\.]+)\))"

def process_numerals(text):

    k = re.split(number_with_both_parantheses, text)
    k = list(filter(None, k))

    for elem in k:
        print(elem)


INPUT = 'Statement 1 (1) Statement 2 (1.1) Statement 3'
expected_output = ['Statement 1', '(1)' , 'Statement 2', '(1.1)', 'Statement 3']


current_output = ['Statement 1', '(1)' , '1', 'Statement 2', '(1.1)', '1.1' , 'Statement 3']
```

My input is the INPUT. I am getting the current_output when call the method 'process_numerals' with input text. How do I shift to expected output ?

Comment: Remove the redundant parentheses from `([\d+\.]+)`, use`number_with_both_parantheses = r"(\(\d+(?:\.\d+)*\))"`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bruHKo/1)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex seems off. You realize that `\(*` checks for zero or more left parentheses?

```
>>> import re
>>> INPUT = 'Statement 1 (1) Statement 2 (1.1) Statement 3'
>>> re.split('\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)', INPUT)
['Statement 1 ', '1', ' Statement 2 ', '1.1', ' Statement 3']
```

If you really want the literal parentheses to be included, put them inside the capturing parentheses.

The non-capturing parentheses `(?:...)` allow you to group without capturing. I guess that's what you are mainly looking for.